# How do I get the contents of all e-mail from a user in Gmail API?

Tags: java, email, gmail-api

I am making an application that should receive the Gmail user emails using Gmail API. However, I must receive the data of each email as content, sender, subject and date received. Has anyone implemented this before?

Follow the section that caught on Google where I can only get the ID and Thread each email id:

```
public class GmailApiQuickstart {

// Check https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes for all available scopes
private static final String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly";
private static final String APP_NAME = "GmailApiQuickstart";
private static final String USER = "me";
// Path to the client_secret.json file downloaded from the Developer Console
private static final String CLIENT_SECRET_PATH = "c:/client_secret.json";

private static GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets;

public void buscar() throws IOException {
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(jsonFactory,  new FileReader(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH));

// Allow user to authorize via url.
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets, Arrays.asList(SCOPE))
.setAccessType("online")
.setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();

String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(GoogleOAuthConstants.OOB_REDIRECT_URI)
.build();
System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then type"
               + " the authorization code:\n" + url);

// Read code entered by user.
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String code = br.readLine();

// Generate Credential using retrieved code.
GoogleTokenResponse responseT = flow.newTokenRequest(code)
.setRedirectUri(GoogleOAuthConstants.OOB_REDIRECT_URI).execute();
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential()
.setFromTokenResponse(responseT);

// Create a new authorized Gmail API client
Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
.setApplicationName(APP_NAME).build();

ListMessagesResponse response = service.users().messages().list(USER).setQ("vagas").execute();

List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
while (response.getMessages() != null) {
  messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
  if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
    String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
    response = service.users().messages().list(USER).setQ("vagas")
        .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
  } else {
    break;
  }
}

for (Message message : messages) {
    //Essa é a parte onde pega o ID e Thread ID
    //qual(ais) parâmetro(s) devo adicionar para pegar o que preciso???
    System.out.println(message.toPrettyString());
}
}

}
```

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

Given the ID of an email, you can fetch the contents using the get method of the [Users.messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) resource. It returns content, sender, subject and date received, To, From fields in the JSON response.

When you fetch a message, you can specify the **payload format** for the response. FULL (the default) format returns the entire parsed message in the payload field. MINIMAL format returns only the metadata such as identifiers and labels. RAW format returns the data as a base64url encoded string within the raw property.